# How to use select statements in control file in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I want to add the following statement in control file(sql load file).

```
select 
123456, 
regexp_replace(123456, '(\d+)(\d{2})', '\1.\2') 
from table_1;
```

Please advice.

Comment: Please explain what do you intend to achieve with this addition.

Comment: Well instead of writing a seperate sql script after the loading has happned i thought if it is posibble to do these changes in the control file itself.

Comment: just put the function next to the column name, in control file.

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle doc mentions the option of [applying SQL operators to fields](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1226). I **guess** that might be what you're looking for. That would be:

```
...
your_number_field             char,
your_regexp_processed_field   char   "regexp_replace(:your_number_field, '(\\d+)(\\d{2})', '\\1.\\2')",
...
```

Anyway, I rather suggest that, instead, you create a view over your `table_1` that does this "calculation" for you.

Comment: But the backslashes have to be escaped?!

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'm not used to SQL*Loader as much so as to do things the 100% correct way on the first attempt. :-) Thank you. Answer corrected.